# Xamarin MasterDetailPage memory leak with custom renderer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, memory-leaks, xamarin.forms

I am using a MasterDetailPage in Xamarin.Forms/Android with each item in the hamburger page representing a page. I change the detail page by calling:

```
Detail = new NavigationPage(new Pages.HomePage());
IsPresented = false;
```

What I have noticed is that the allocation for this page is somewhat large (it's requesting like 22mb). Not only that, but if I were to repeatedly press the sidebar's home button, I get an OutOfMemoryException after about 5 clicks. So something isn't clicking with the Garbage Collection.

The home page has a custom renderer that essentially composites an image using three png files. This works with minimal slowdown on my phone, but the emulator lags significantly when it is on screen, leading me to believe that it is causing performance issues.

```
public class GoalJarViewRenderer : ImageRenderer
{

    Bitmap fillBmp = null;
    Bitmap jarHud = null;
    Paint font;
    Paint fontBold;
    string goalString = "";
    string progString = "";

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
    {
        this.SetWillNotDraw(false);
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Element.PropertyChanged += SignalUpdate;

        //Cache       
        if (fillBmp == null) fillBmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(this.Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.jar_fill);
        if (jarHud == null) jarHud = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(this.Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.jar_hud);
        if (font == null)
        {
            font = new Paint();
            font.AntiAlias = true;
            font.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.White;
            font.TextSize = 50;
            font.TextAlign = Paint.Align.Center;
        }
        if (fontBold == null)
        {
            fontBold = new Paint(font);
            fontBold.FakeBoldText = true;
            fontBold.TextSize = 80;
        }
    }


    private void SignalUpdate(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        GoalJarView handle = (GoalJarView)this.Element;
        goalString = String.Format("${0:#0.0#} / ${1:##.##}", handle.CurrentValue, handle.GoalValue);
        progString = String.Format("{0:##0.00}%", (handle.CurrentValue / handle.GoalValue) * 100);
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.Draw(canvas);

        //Draw the fill
        double LID_FIX = 0.91;
        GoalJarView handle = (GoalJarView)this.Element;
        double fillRatio = Math.Min(1,((handle.CurrentValue * LID_FIX) / handle.GoalValue));
        int srcStartY = (int)(fillBmp.Height - Math.Floor(fillBmp.Height * fillRatio));
        int destStartY = (int)(canvas.Height - Math.Floor(canvas.Height * fillRatio));
        Rect fillSrc = new Rect(0, srcStartY, fillBmp.Width, fillBmp.Height);
        RectF fillDest = new RectF(0, destStartY, canvas.Width, canvas.Height);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(fillBmp, fillSrc, fillDest, null);

        //Draw the text container
        canvas.DrawBitmap(jarHud, null, new Rect(0,0,canvas.Width,canvas.Height), null);

        //Draw the Text
        canvas.DrawText(progString, canvas.Width / 2, (canvas.Height / 2) - 20, fontBold);
        canvas.DrawText(goalString, canvas.Width / 2, (canvas.Height / 2) + 30, font);

    }
}
```

I was told that BitmapFactory.DecodeResource was incredibly taxing, so I moved that into the OnElementChanged rather than the draw function. I don't see anything else immediately taxing inside of Draw(), but I am new to Xamarin/Android and assume the problem is glaringly obvious to a seasoned developer.

I have tried creating local variables on the MasterDetailPage that stores pages so they don't need to be created every time an item is pressed, but this led to crashing when the page reopened, as the actual control class that stores the data bindings was null.

What is causing this memory leak, and how can I correct it?

Comment: Which emulator did you use the `Android Emulator for Visual Studio` or the native android emulator that you installed via AVD Manager? Have tested it on real device?

Comment: I am using XAP, but I have confirmed that the crash occurs on a real device after the same amount of clicks. I have remedied the problem by overriding the **Dispose()** function and calling Dispose() on the cached bitmaps, but I feel like the performance is still sluggish when the page loads (you can see slight pop-in on a real device).